# Value is not updated for the key when using redis-plus-plus library using docker container

Tags: c++, docker, redis

I am trying to get the value for the specific key using [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) library. I do not have any problems connecting the library and receive value when it is created by a separate container. The problem begins when value is updated for the same key on redis.
Here is the code that I am using to connect and to get the value:

```
// This is how I am connecting to redis
try {
    if ( !redisUrl.has_value() || redisUrl->empty() )
        throw std::runtime_error( "Redis url is not set" );

    std::cout << "Trying to connect to redis server: " << *redisUrl << std::endl;
    m_redis = std::make_unique<sw::redis::Redis>( *redisUrl );
} catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
    std::cout << "Caught an exception when trying to connect to redis: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    m_redis.reset();
}

// This is how I am using it
try {

    if ( !m_redis ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "redis is not connected." );
    }
            
    auto val = m_redis->get( key );
    if ( val ) {
        std::cout << "Using value: " << *val << std::endl;        
    }
} catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

And when I am trying to use get() for the client, I am receiving old value and not the updated one. Is this an issue from the library? Because I went inside the container and saw that the value is updated on redis server itself. Thanks in advance

Comment: The code looks good to me. Is it possible that your `get` call runs before you update the value? Or you connect to a wrong Redis server?

Comment: That is not possible. I double checked such scenarios.

Comment: Try this with redis-cli once and check what happens. Like from your clients run redis-cli and check what values you get.

Comment: I have already checked, with redis-cli everything is updated, I think library caches this values somehow.

Comment: No, the library [does not cache anything](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/blob/master/src/sw/redis%2B%2B/redis.cpp#L313-L317). Are you sure it's connecting to the same server?

Comment: Sure, 100%, after updating library to the latest version it begins to work, but still there is a delay in a minute or so